# Why LIKE without wildcards does not work

Tags: python, sqlite

I might be asking a silly question, but I really need to know. Let's imagine a query like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '%monitor%'")
```

This query will return all the items with *monitor* in the field topic_simple, including "monitoring", "monitorate", or whatever.

If I do:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE 'monitor'")
```

The query returns nothing, not even the items with "monitor" (as a simple word) are returned. And that bothers me, I don't understand why.

I use both the sqlite from PyQt and from sqlite3, and I have the same result.

Is there a way to get the items with "monitor" (as a simple word, whith nothing behind or in front of) with a LIKE query ?

EDIT: here is what a typical topic_simple looks like:

```
we report that a tree like polymer of lysine is able to form a multi ligand complex with a fluorescently labelled peptide leading to the almost complete extinction of the optical signal that can be restored upon the introduction of heparin this simple system allows for the first time the turn on fluorescent sensing of the anticoagulant in human blood at clinically relevant levels monitoring clinical levels of heparin in human blood samples with an indicator displacement assay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to you guys, I figured out why it didn't work. I thought LIKE was an equivalent to something like CONTAINS.

If I want to return all the items containing the word "monitor", and strictly monitor, not monitoring or anything else, the query must be:

```
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% monitor %'
```

Note the spaces between monitor and %.

Answer (score 1):

`foo LIKE bar` is the exact equivalent of `foo = bar`. If `LIKE monitor` doesn't return anything, then your field value must have something ELSE in there, like `[space]monitor` or `monitor[space]`. Anything that'd throw off a straight equality test.

Try

```
SELECT length(topic_simple) FROM your table WHERE topic_simple LIKE '%monitor%';
```

If you DON'T get `7` as the result for where "monitor" should be by itself, then you've got extra characters in the field.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, yes topic_simple contains a lot of other things, it's basically a simple text See my edit, and the comment to @simplycoding.

Comment: then yes, if there's other stuff in the field, you'll have to use a wildcarded `like`. a straight equality test, `foo=bar` REQUIRES the contents of both sides by identical. `'foo' = 'foo*'` is false, because they're NOT identical.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote your value, as any other value. Currently, you're first query is a lookup for a field called `%monitor%` and you compare with the field `monitor`.

You should just use `"`-quotes:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE "%monitor%"')
```

For readability i replaced the other `"`to `'`.

Comment: Yes yes of course I quote them, that was just a simplified example. In the real life, the field is programmaticaly replaced anyway. Thanks to mention it, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data to see if there are any spaces in the fields that seem to contain just `monitor`. There are probably trailing or leading spaces that you can't see in there, making the LIKE comparison return nothing

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, yes topic_simple contains a lot of other things, it's basically a simple text See my edit. I think I need something like "return the item if topic_simple contains this_word".